# Segmentation-error: am I using malloc correctly for array size?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

So I"ve been writing a program that asks the user for different input.

It then creates an array outside the main function using malloc, allocating memory depending on user input.

The array is then filled out with randomly generated numbers (that part actually works I tested it in a smaller program.

Compiling the program I get these warnings

> m0.c:40:15: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion 
>   passing 'int' to parameter of
>          type 'int *'; remove * [-Wint-conversion]
>        fillArray(*array, arraylength, lowerLimit, upperLimit);
>                  ^~~~~~ m0.c:18:20: note: passing argument to parameter here int* fillArray (int[], int, int, int);
>
> ^ m0.c:41:19: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of
>          type 'int *'; remove * [-Wint-conversion]
>        search_number(*array, arraylength);
>                      ^~~~~~ m0.c:21:25: note: passing argument to parameter here void search_number (int*, int);
>                            ^

related to line 40 `fillArray(*array, arraylength, lowerLimit, upperLimit);` 
and
line 41 `search_number(*array, arraylength).

I don't understand the warnings, the pattern of using the array as *array worked before (I created another program where there was no input or memory allocation due to the variables being declared as `const` ).

This is how it looks like when started:

> How many values would you like?
>
> 12
>
> Lower limit of random numbers:
>
> 20
>
> Upper limit of random numbers:
>
> 33 
>   Segmentation fault: 11

I researched the definition of a segmentation-fault and it must be related to wrong memory allocation.

I also might be using pointers wrong, but I don't understand the source of my mistake as I've used a similar syntax in my code before.

This is how I allocated the memory for the array (with previously defined user input as a parameter.

```
int* init_array(int arraylength)
{
    int *array = malloc ((arraylength) * (sizeof (int)));

    return array;
}
```

---

With `MAX_INT` being declared as a fixed `#define` variable this was no issue before, this code

```
void search_number (int* array)
{

    int number = input ();
    int counter = 0;
    output(array);
    for (int i=0; i<MAX_INT; i++)
    {
        if ((*(array+i))==number)
            {
               counter++;
            }
    }
    printf ("\nThe number %d occurs %d times.", number, counter);
}
```

gives me the desired output.

Comment: Please format the error messages more readably.

Comment: The problem isn't in the function you posted. It's in the code that calls `fillArray` and `search_number`. The first argument should just be `array`, not `*array`.

Comment: `*array` returns the value of the first element of the "array". Therefore the type of `*array` is `int`. On the other side your function takes a `int*`, so pass `array` instead of `*array`.

Comment: but I thought I needed to give it the address of the array, so int*array for int array []

Comment: Given `int *array;` when used in an expression `array` evals as the value of the pointer (i.e. an address). `*array` evaluates as the value of what the pointer *points to* (i.e. an `int`). The compiler is telling you as much; you're passing an `int` to a function expecting an `int *`. Pass `array`, and review the section of whatever book/tutorial/human is providing instruction on pointers in C.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<MAX_INT; i++)` leads to undefined behavior due to `int` overflow.  `*(array+i)` lacks enough memory allocation.

Comment: I don't get warnings or errors for the code in the lower part though. It works for me as intended for some reason. But thank you for answering I will try to figure this out

Comment: Don't use `*(array+i)`.  Just use `array[i]`.  They're equivalent. That's why the `[]` syntax exists. Also, with the warnings you're getting, you shouldn't attempt to run the code.  It can't possibly work.  Fix the warnings first.  The compiler pointed you right at them.  That's what you needed to post.